# How to conditionally format (i.e. highlighting) cell contents depending on the word that appear in MS Word

Tags: sharepoint, ms-word

I have created a list in SharePoint that creates a word document from a template in a document library. The 'Status' of the project is either green, yellow, or red. How the heck can I change the highlighting of the word that appears in the cell depending on which word appears?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly you want to highlight column values in document library list view and your field 'Status' exists in this document library and its value set in MS Word created from template. If it is your case then good choice to use CSR (Client Side Rendering).

This is javascript code that can be added by different ways:
1. You can add Content Editor (or Script Editor) Web Part with this CSR javascript to document library list view page and your column will be highlighted.
2. You can programmatically add JSLink to CSR javascript code to specific column. Each field object has JSLink property. See SP.Field.jsLink in sp.js.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj244927.aspx
3. You can open list view web part settings on document library list view page and in Miscellanious section set JSLink property to url of CSR javascript file.

CSR javascript file you can locate in some library, ex.Style Library or Site Assets.

CSR allow to change view, column rendering logic.

This links will be helpful for you:

https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/114097/csr-coloured-colum

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/599db8b2-0d5d-4f82-bffc-06a8215e2454/jslink-color-code-background-entire-cell?forum=sharepointcustomization